# Exception Handling Between Functions c++

Tags: c++, exception, stringstream

I'm taking a basic OOP in C++ class. One of our assignments is to read lines from a file, run them through a function (parseLine()) that converts a string to a string stream, throw exceptions from that parseLine, catch the exceptions in the readFile function and write the lines that threw exceptions to the console. The lines that did not throw exceptions should be added to a struct array.

**The problem:** The throws are not being thrown, or not being caught.

I have spent hours playing with the formatting trying to figure out why my try catch statement isn't working. I wish I could ask a more specific question, but I believe the answer will be obvious to a more experienced programmer who sees my code

Note: Formatting style is prescribed by the class.

```
/**********************************************************************
* struct: Record
* fileName
* user
* time
***********************************************************************/
struct Record
{
   string file;
   string user;
   long time;
};

/**********************************************************************
* function: parseLine
* parse line into struct
***********************************************************************/
void parseLine(const string & line, Record & buffer) throw (string)
{
   assert(line.length() > 0);

   stringstream ss;
   ss.str(line);

   // stream string to struct
   ss >> buffer.file;
   if (ss.fail())
   {
      ss.clear();
      throw string(line);
   }
   ss >> buffer.user;
   if (ss.fail())
   {
      ss.clear();
      throw string(line);
   }

   ss >> buffer.time;
   if (ss.fail() || buffer.time < 1,000,000,000 || buffer.time > 10,000,000,000)
   {
      ss.clear();
      throw string(line);
   }
}

/**********************************************************************
* function: readFile
* read from the file name provided by the user
***********************************************************************/
int readFile(const string & fileName, Record record[])
{
   // declare fstream variable
   ifstream fin(fileName.c_str());

   // error check
   if (fin.fail())
   {
      cout << "ERROR: Unable to read file "
           << fileName
           << endl;
      return 0;        
   }

   // loop through file and store it
   Record buffer;
   string line;
   int size = 0;
   while (getline(fin, line) && size < 500)
   {
      try
      {
         parseLine(line, buffer);
         record[size] = buffer;
      }
      catch (string text)
      {
         cout << "Error parsing line: "
              << text
              << endl;
      }
      size++;
   }

   // close the file
   fin.close();
   return size;
}
```

**Question 1** The file being read purposely contains errors (Empty lines, ints in unexpected places, etc), it seems like the ss.fail() is not being triggered, how could that happen?

**Question 2** Is my try/catch block written correctly?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: This is your assignment?  IMHO this is an real abuse of exceptions.

Comment: Reading strings can't fail.

Comment: small remark: throw(type) has been deprecated in C++ in favor of noexcept

Comment: Have you tried `!ss.good()` instead of `ss.fail()`? The latter is not triggered by every possible error you'll encounter.

Comment: -NathanOliver lol, yeah especially when I'm perusing these forums I realize how out of sync what we're learning is with common practice.
-latedeveloper what should fail is when there's nothing left in the string to read, or streaming a string into an int
-JVApen I hope I learn what that means eventually! =)
-lorro Thanks for that tip! I just tried it, but the exception is not thrown =(
Thank you all for commenting! I appreciate the insights.

Comment: Your integer literals should not contain commas.

Comment: @Anon thanks for pointing that out! I'll see if that changes the overall.

Comment: @Anon That was it! Somehow when I took out the commas it changed everything!... why would that be? Also, for some reason I can't upvote your answer. I hope someone does, because that solved it.

Comment: I added it as an answer.

Comment: I'm in a sandbox! :'(

Answer (score 0):

Your integer literals should not contain commas.

The comma is actually a C++ operator.